# What are the limits of extension tubes?

Tags: aperture, extension-tubes

Given lighting is not a problem, can you hit a limit where you have too much extension tubes (a very long tube) and the quality of the image will suffer?  For example a diffraction limit will be hit for the adjusted F-Stop or something like that?

What are the variables that come into play here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if I put 68 mm of tube (36+20+12) behind my 12-24 lens, I can't focus on a subject because the focus point is behind the front lens.

Comment: Can you explain the three numbers?

Comment: @Reid: I have a kit with three extension tubes, one 36 mm one 20 mm and one 12 mm.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought that you were presenting a computed answer (i.e., 68mm was theoretically significant somehow), but instead you're relating a personal experience. Thanks for the clarification.